# Преобразования JS

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток!
Вопрос легкий, не судите строго)
Есть числовой массив строк.
Как его преобразовать в просто числовой?

```
 var array = ["1", "3", "5", "7", "9", "8", "6", "4", "2"] ==>
          ==>[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

Comment: пробежаться с помощью `map` и конвертнув каждое значение через `parseInt`

Answer (score 4):

Можно так, например:

```
array = array.map(num => parseInt(num));
```

Answer (score 0):

Почти такой же ответ как у [@YuS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/222962/yus), только используя оператор и ещё тут также могут пройти числа, типа `float` (`0.42`).

```js
var array = ["1", "3", "5", "7", "9", "8", "6", "4", "2"]

array = array.map(e => +e)

console.log(array)
```

Также способ для поддержки старых браузеров:

```js
var array = ["1", "3", "5", "7", "9", "8", "6", "4", "2"]

for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = Number(array[i])
}

console.log(array)
```

Во втором случае используется `Number` вместо оператора `+`, т.к. более старая версия Оперы начала поддерживать сначала `Number`, а потом только ун. оператор `+`.